# How to stop Google App Script is duplicating copies?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm hoping someone can help me with a script I am trying to write.

I am trying to write a script so that when a new row is added to our google sheet, it will copy a template spreadsheet and paste the link into the corresponding column. The sheet is updated automatically when a new person signs up.

The script below can copy the template sheet, rename it based on the adjacent text in row A and then and paste the link in column 20.

Unfortunately, every time it runs it creates new sheets for all rows in the sheet, instead of just finding the latest row  and creating 1 new sheet.

Also, I want to set the share permissions for the new share the spreadsheet to a certain group, rather than anyone with the link.

```
////function copyTo() {
// var tempsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1q....");
//var mastersheet = tempsheet.getSheetByName("Setting Sheet");
//var lrow = mastersheet.getLastRow();
//for (i= 2; i<lrow; i++ ) {
//let names = mastersheet.getRange(i,1).getValues();
//sheet = tempsheet.copy(names);
//}
//}

//function createSpreadsheet(){
//var tempsheet = '1....';
//var sheetName = "MASTER"
//SpreadsheetApp.openById(tempsheet).copy(sheetName);

//for (r=2; r<lrow; r++) {
//let name = ss.getRange(r,1).getValue();


function cloneGoogleSheet(fileName) {
  var destFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("19Q....");
  var newFile = DriveApp.getFileById("1vvgD....").makeCopy(fileName, destFolder);
  return newFile.getUrl();
}

function createSheets() {
  var workBook = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = workBook.getSheetByName("Sheet1")
  var data = sheet.getRange("A2:A" + sheet.getLastRow()).getValues()

  data.forEach((row, index) => {
    sheet.getRange(index + 2, 20).setValue(cloneGoogleSheet(row[0]))
  })

}
```

Any help you could give me would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: `data.forEach()` will create a new file for every row of column A containing data.  So if you add a new row of data the `forEach` will create a new file for the old data as well as the new row data.  You probable need to include a check if the url exists skip the copy process.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. The script doesn't include anything to "just finding the latest spreasdsheet entry" and to "share the spreadsheet with the same group". If you haven't done this yet, please read https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets. If you need further help, I suggest you to focus your question on one specific issue, show what you have tried to solve and include a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask] related to that issue.

Answer (score 0):

## SUGGESTION *[UPDATED]*

> **Note:** Your post contains multiple questions, which is not advisable in stackoverflow as every question should only discuss one specific issue. This answer will only only tackle the first question ***How to stop Google App Script is duplicating copies?*** As for the ***second question***, kindly file a separate stackoverflow question for it.

Your main goal is to copy **one unique template** of the spreadsheet and paste its link in the corresponding column ***(column #20 from your sample script)*** adjacent to the newly inserted/added row in the Sheet file every time your API inserts a new user sign up info.

I suggest using a [Time-driven installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers). This way, you will be able to run a script (e.g. every number of minutes/hours or time of the day) that will capture new row(s) of data in your sheet being updated by your API.

For more context, here's a tweaked script for this implementation & its demonstration below.

## Tweaked Script:

```
var workBook = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = workBook.getSheetByName("Sheet1");

function storeLastRow() { //Run this once here in the editor to kickstart the whole script
  try {
    const scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
    scriptProperties.setProperty('LAST_ROW', sheet.getLastRow());
    const recentRow = scriptProperties.getProperty('LAST_ROW');
    console.log("Last Row recorded: "+ recentRow); //LOG FOR TRACKING
  } catch (err) {
    Logger.log('Failed with error %s', err.message);
  }
}

function captureNewRow() {
  const scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  const recentRow = scriptProperties.getProperty('LAST_ROW');
  createSheets(parseInt(recentRow));
  storeLastRow(); //This will auto-store the new last row on your script for the next time trigger
}

function createSheets(recentRow) {
  console.log("LAST ROW RECORDED: "+recentRow+"\nCURRENT LAST ROW: "+sheet.getLastRow()); //LOG FOR TRACKING
    for(var i = recentRow; i < sheet.getLastRow(); i++){ //Loop through the new rows one-by-one and save a dedicated copy per new rows
      var filename = sheet.getRange((i+1),1).getValue();
      sheet.getRange((i+1), 20).setValue(cloneGoogleSheet(filename))
      console.log("Done processing new row #"+ (i+1)); //LOG FOR TRACKING
    }
}

function cloneGoogleSheet(fileName) {
  var destFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1VaI...");
  var newFile = DriveApp.getFileById("1oJ2...").makeCopy(fileName, destFolder);
  return newFile.getUrl();
}
```

## Demonstration:

- Firstly, run the `storeLastRow` function **once** to kick start the process. This will store the current last row in your sheet.

---

> [image]

- Next, create a time-driven trigger for the `captureNewRow` function (in my testing, I run it every minute):

---

> [image]

- Let's say there's a new row of data added on the sheet (as seen below) & after a few minutes, the `captureNewRow` function runs and adds the copy of the template file on the **column 20** adjacent to the new row:

> [image]

- If multiple rows of data were added on the sheet before the next time trigger run, the `captureNewRow` function can also process them as seen below:

> [image]

Comment: @Mr Potato Please check the info above. Feel free to comment in case you have follow up questions. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply. 

I can see you solution works perfetly based on the way I phrase my question of adding a row. What I actually meant was when text is added to the row.

So for example, there is an api running which updates rows 1 at a time and adds it to the next available row on the sheet. The onchange trigger works, but it should pickup the last populated row. Hope that makes sense and is something you can help with? 

Thanks :)

Comment: @MrPotato I see. So the next available row is being populated automatically by the API, does this mean the sheet isn't being updated manually by any user? Also, kindly update your post and explain how your setup works for better understanding.

Comment: Thanks Irvin. I've updated my post to try and better describe the setup.

Comment: Hmm.. if the sheet row is being updated automatically without any user interaction, it seems the only way is via using a time-driven trigger (also called a clock trigger). I'll take a look...

Comment: @MrPotato I have updated the info above. It seems this can only be possible using the `time-driven trigger`.